# No transmissions seen in 1Gpbs network

Tags: networking, tcp

I have 2 machines connected to a switch via 1Gb Ethernet cables. I am sending TCP traffic from one host to another. I wanted to see how many re-transmitted packets are there from sender side using netstats. to my chagrin, there was not any re-transmission. Should not the cwnd grow too large and packet loss should occur, resulting in re-transmission. Need expaination.

Comment: Where retransmission should be taken from? Where do you see the source for packet loss in your scheme?

Comment: I have not seen any packet loss. But considering the way TCP congestion algorithm work, should not cwnd at some point grow too large that packet loss at the switch occur? I don't understand no packet loss in this case.

Comment: Why would it grow too large?

Comment: Because cwnd increases every rtt, and tcp sends at  cwnd/ rtt rate. The rate would eventually exceed the network bandwidth of 1Gbps. (I have run the TCP flow for a fairly long time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work as you are expecting.
The cwnd/rtt rate does increase but it can't get any further than the physical transmision speed on the underlying interface can process.
Your expected re-transmissions never show because the output queue throttles itself before that point is reached. The data-delay caused by the throttling happens in the application output buffer which is not visible in the information netstat shows.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!